# Does $element['#title'] need to be escaped with check_plain()?

Tags: 7, theming

I see (with grep) that the value of `$element['#title']` in a render element is sometimes sanitized with `check_plain()`, and sometimes printed unfiltered.

Which one is correct? Is the value considered safe to print? Or does it depend on the theme hook?

Examples from core:

```
modules/field/field.form.inc
314:        'data' => '<label>' . t('!title !required', array('!title' => $element['#title'], '!required' => $required)) . "</label>",
```

(notice the "!" in the placeholder, this means that `format_string()` will not escape the placeholder value)

```
modules/field/field.module
1052:  $variables['label'] = $variables['label_hidden'] ? NULL : check_plain($element['#title']);
```

This question applies in both ways:

- When setting `$element['#title']` in a render element.
- When printing the value of `$element['#title']`.
- When printing a `$variables['title']` value that was extracted from a render element property.

Note: Very often the `$element['#title']` property comes directly from a `t()` call.

Answer (score 1):

It's user input and should be considered unsafe; you should always sanitise it.

For the specific example you've given where it isn't, the title is already sanitised before it's passed to the theme function containing the `t()` call. This happens in [`field_multiple_value_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.form.inc/function/field_multiple_value_form/7.x)

```
$title = check_plain($instance['label']);

...

$element = array(
  ...
  '#title' => $multiple ? '' : $title,
  ...
);
```

As an aside, if you ever did need to preserve HTML in the title for whatever reason, you could consider using [`filter_xss()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/filter_xss/7.x) instead.

Comment: <strike>You are contradicting yourself, sort of</strike>. In the given example, `$title` is raw user input, but `$element['#title']` is not. So it seems it depends on the render element type.

Comment: Also the distinction is not necessarily about html vs plain text, but about trusted vs non-trusted.

Comment: Sure, I was just referring to the fact that `check_plain` removes HTML and not using it preserves it. If you're asking whether `#title` in _any_ render array, ever, can be trusted then yes the answer is definitely "it depends", because render array properties are arbitrary, and what a `#title` is to a form element isn't necessarily the same thing as it is to a different type of element. I assumed you were asking about the field module specifically because of the examples. It's been a long child-filled day so I might also be missing something about what you're asking ;)

Comment: Hmm, having re-read I think maybe i am contradicting myself here after all. You're absolutely right, if it was the same `#title` it wouldn't need to be escaped again. Will try to have a deeper look a bit later

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to check with `check_plain()` to prevent cross site scripting attacks in the first example from `modules/field/field.form.inc` `$element['#title']` passed as `arg` to `t` function.
if you look at [t function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/t/7.x) source code it call [format_string](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/format_string/7.x) function it check plain `$args[$key] = check_plain($value);`.

Comment: Actually no, in the first example the placeholder is "!title" with "!", which means no escaping will happen in format_string().